# WordPress 4.7 jquery undefined from scratch

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When installing a WordPress 4.7 de-DE and afterwards using it (no plugins installed), it tells me in the console that the jquery is missing /not defined. What do I need to do to activate it? It is mainly in the admin area where this problem occurs.

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.7:3  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.7:3
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.7:3

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at admin.js?ver=1482949191:1(anonymous) @ admin.js?ver=1482949191:1
admin-notice-hider.js?version=1.6.0&ver=4.7:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at admin-notice-hider.js?version=1.6.0&ver=4.7:1
```

Comment: What theme are you using? WordPress is already including jQuery so this issue shouldn't exist in a default theme.

Comment: @Siavas First "Primashop" but after you mentioned it, I tested it with the 3 included themes and all of those cause the same problem.

Comment: Was any of these 3 included themes one created by Automattic? For example, Twenty Sixteen, Twenty Fifteen, etc.

Comment: @Siavas yes, it was those :)

Comment: Perhaps not all files got uploaded? I'd suggest to reinstall it while it's fresh tbh. If it's in admit area, chances that theme has anything to do with it are rather small

Comment: @IgorYavych Through WP-Admin but also through re-uploading and overwriting all files except the wp-config.php it doesn't work. Not sure if this is the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to add a link to the Jquery CDN in admin-header.php of wp-admin/ 
I don't know why it works now but somehow it may not have been included in the WP 4.7?!

Comment: It might have been that not all the files where in place, just as @Igor mentioned in the comments. I have used WP 4.7 and jQuery was enabled from the beginning. Might be even because of the language you have downloaded it in (de-DE). If so, you may even consider reporting [this issue](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/)..

Comment: Also, as you have discovered the solution yourself, it's best to mark your answer as the solution for other people to see it at the top when they come across the question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to go into your theme's root folder (e.g. `wp-content/themes/primashop/`), search for `functions.php` file, then serach for the string `wp_enqueue_scripts`, and you will find a function where all scripts and style sheets are imported.

Just before other scripts that require jQuery, add the following line, which will import the bundled jQuery script into your theme:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

This is the same way you will also need to add other scripts and style sheets in your theme. Doing it the other way (inserting `<script>` and `<link>` tags into themes' files is likely to cause problems, especially with the scripts).

Keep in mind that jQuery will only be available for the theme where you add this line. It is required to do the same for other themes where you see this issue.

---

For adding scripts, use `wp_enqueue_script`.

For adding style sheets, use `wp_enqueue_style`.

Learn more at WordPress Codex about the [enqueue script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [style sheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) functions.

Comment: Thanks Siavas, but unfortunately this also does not work as there is real function where this happens. There are a few occasions but mainly just to import fonts and after implementing your coe line, it doesn't work...

Comment: @Lars, do you have a new WordPress installation where only the wp-config.php file has been changed for connection to the database?